# Binding to a object which also implements IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have the following class:

```
public class FunctionList : IEnumerable<Function> {
   public string Comments {get; set;}

    public IEnumerator<Function> GetEnumerator() {
        return ...;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

An object of this class is used as a datasource for Binding in a WinForm:

```
this.checkEdit1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(nameof(this.checkEdit1.EditValue), functionList, nameof(functionList.Comments), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

The problem is, that the Binding is not working, when the `dataSource` (`functionList`) implements `IEnumerable<>`. When I remove this Interface, it is working correct. Otherwise I get the following `ArgumentException`:

```
Cannot bind to the property or column Comments on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember
```

What can I do to get the binding working when the `dataSource` implements `IEnumerable<>`?

Comment: Any reason behind a custom `IEnumerable` instead of using one of the many built-in types like `List<T>`?

Comment: I need the object somewhere other with the IEnumerable<>-Interface. But at this binding-scenario it should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

> IEnumerable
>
> > Windows Forms controls can be bound to data sources that only support the IEnumerable interface if they are bound through a
> >     BindingSource component.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/data-sources-supported-by-windows-forms

Comment: The goal is, that the Binding-Mechanism is ignoring the IEnumerable<>-Interface.

Comment: @BennoDual That's what the docs says is going to happen. You need to use a BindingSource for it to work.

Comment: The docs says that when I want to bind to the IEnumerable I need a BindingSource. But do not want to bind to the IEnumerable-Interface. I want only bind to a simple Property.